# fadeIn, fadeOut jQuery code snippet

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 520) {
        $('.element').fadeIn();
    } if ($(this).scrollTop() < 520) {
        $('.element').stop().fadeOut();
    }
});
```

I put it together like this so that the element fades in after 520 and fades out if less than 520. My question is the following: Are they brackets correct or would it be better to make it differently?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'are the brackets' correct, but if you mean the syntax then it's fine. All I would suggest you change is the second `if` statement to an `else`, otherwise you're missing the case where `scrollTop` = 520 exactly.

Comment: you missed the else like  `} else if ($(this).scrollTop() < 520) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is sort of off topic for this section, but check out this part of SO: [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Syntax looks good but as others have said you might want to change it to else if, or an else depending on what you want.

Here is the best resource I've found on if/else statements:

[MDN If. . . Else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)